# Type into console core azure app and give access to that app to end users

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, azure-web-app-service

I deployed my console net core app to azure. How can i write something to my published console app bcause my console app takes some values from user and prints out, i cannot find link to this deployed application and then how to give access to end user to that console app?

Comment: Hi , has your issue been solved?

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, you published a .net core console app as Azure Webjobs, and you are looking for a webhook so that you can let your users access this console app. You also need to know how to pass params to it via webhook.

I did a simple .net core console demo for you:

```
using System;

namespace coreconsoleparam
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("agrs received :");
                foreach (string arg in args) {
                    Console.WriteLine(arg+ " ");
                }
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("received no args");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have published to Azure Webjobs of my web app. You can find its webhook here :

[image]

You can call your console app by POST method with username and password by Http Basic Auth, just as below :

[image]

[image]

As you can see, in this request URL, there is a param named `arguments`, you can use it to pass params to your console app.

You will get a "202 Accepted" response if you called your app successfully.

Finally, let's check its log :
[image]

As you can see, the app has been executed successfully and all params has been received .

Hope it helps.