# How to call azure web jobs and pass params

Tags: azure, api, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I have a .net core console app and I want to host it on Azure web jobs.

For now I can trigger it manually and it works as excepted .But is there a way to trigger it by some rest apis? I want to use my code to trigger it .what’s more, based on my logic, I need pass more than one parameters to it , is it possible ? Any assistance is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can trigger your webjobs by http webhook and you can also pass params to your console app which hosted on Azure webjobs. For details, [pls see my previous post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438184/type-into-console-core-azure-app-and-give-access-to-that-app-to-end-users/59464041#59464041) .

Comment: What about more complex parameters than can be represented on the query string?